# How to depend on Terraform aws aws_autoscaling_group's ec2 instance state and status

Tags: terraform

I have a Terraform module that needs to depend on the resource aws_autoscaling_group ec2 "Instance State" and "Status Checks" (from the ec2 console) to go green before starting. How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding that's the default behavior of `autoscaling_group`. From [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html):

> Terraform provides two mechanisms to help consistently manage ASG scale uptime across dependent resources.
>
> The first is the default behavior. Terraform waits after ASG creation for `min_size` (or `desired_capacity`, if specified) healthy instances to show up in the ASG before continuing.

[...]

> Terraform considers an instance "healthy" when the ASG reports HealthStatus: "Healthy" and LifecycleState: "InService"

Also, from the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroupLifecycle.html):

> When each instance is fully configured and passes the Amazon EC2 health checks, it is attached to the Auto Scaling group and it enters the InService state. The instance is counted against the desired capacity of the Auto Scaling group.